# Get releated JIRA issue changelist through Fisheye rest api

Tags: perforce, jira-rest-java-api, changelist, atlassian-fisheye

I want to get changelist from jira issue (in source tab) by key or others, But it seems that jira rest client api doesn't provide method to get it. Then I try to get changelist through fisheye api.I  still can not find this in fisheye restful api. Is it possible to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by myself. Get CL through fisheye restful api by EQL. See https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/29439/getting-the-list-of-changesets-associated-with-an-issue-in-jira. I think it is a good solution.